# Как отредактировать style.min.css

Tags: css, wordpress

На WordPress установил шаблон, который берет стили из файла style.min.css . Пробовал отредактировать style.css , но изменений в стилях нет. Подскажите как его можно внести изменения в style.min.css ?

Comment: Файл может быть закеширован

Answer (score 4):

То, что вы называете шаблоном, в WordPress именуется темой - совокупность файлов, изменяющих внешний вид WordPress. А шаблон в WP - это один php-файл для отображения некой одной сущности - страницы, категории и т.п.

По сути вопроса. В теме надо искать файл (скорее всего, это functions.php), который содержит подключение стиля через `wp_enqueue_style()`. В аргументах функции надо заменить `style.min.css` на `style.css`.

Но лучше тему править через [дочернюю тему](https://wp-kama.ru/id_6235/dochernie-temy-wordpress.html), иначе при обновлении ваши правки слетят.

Другой способ - используйте сервис минификации css, например [CSS Minifier](https://cssminifier.com/) и замените style.min.css в теме. Но помните, что при обновлении, ваш файл будет перезаписан.

Третий способ - используйте кастомайзер. Там можно править внешний вид визуально или добавить свой css.

Comment: Про кастомайзер забыл..

Comment: @SeVlad добавил

Comment: Не нашел ни в functions.php ни в других файлах wp_enqueue_style(). Может сможете подсказать, что необходимо прописать для замены.
Путь откуда тянет стиль:
<link rel="stylesheet" id="wp-block-library-css" href="мойсайт/wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/style.min.css?ver=5.7.2" type="text/css" media="all">

Comment: @ДимаБальжик это файл стилей блочного редактора, к теме WordPress не имеет отношения. Он в ядре WordPress. Править его нельзя, правки слетят при обновлении ядра. Эти стили надо перекрывать своими стилями, которые можно добавить через кастомайзер.